# wordpress site kills mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, wordpress

I move client wordpress sites from one VPS to another, it all went smooth until I moved a site that kills mysql (and, consequently, all other wp sites). It used to work fine on the previous VPS.

Here's the info I have so far. Before opening in browser that site, `systemctl status mysql.service -l` gives

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2015-11-11 08:48:22 MSK; 14min ago
  Process: 6404 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6400 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6403 (mysqld_safe)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           ├─6403 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
           └─6761 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306

Nov 11 08:48:21 jupiter-clean systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Nov 11 08:48:21 jupiter-clean mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 08:48:21 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
Nov 11 08:48:21 jupiter-clean mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 08:48:21 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
Nov 11 08:48:21 jupiter-clean mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 08:48:21 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Nov 11 08:48:22 jupiter-clean systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Nov 11 09:03:01 jupiter-clean systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Going to that site makes `systemctl status mysql.service -l` output

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2015-11-11 09:05:14 MSK; 1min 17s ago
  Process: 6404 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6403 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6400 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6403 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 11 08:48:21 jupiter-clean systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Nov 11 08:48:21 jupiter-clean mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 08:48:21 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
Nov 11 08:48:21 jupiter-clean mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 08:48:21 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
Nov 11 08:48:21 jupiter-clean mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 08:48:21 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Nov 11 08:48:22 jupiter-clean systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Nov 11 09:03:01 jupiter-clean systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Nov 11 09:05:14 jupiter-clean mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 09:05:14 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
Nov 11 09:05:14 jupiter-clean mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 09:05:14 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
Nov 11 09:05:14 jupiter-clean mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 09:05:14 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Here's the `/var/log/mysql/error.log`:

```
151111 09:05:14 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
151111 09:05:14 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-11-11 09:05:14 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-11-11 09:05:14 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27-0ubuntu1) starting as process 6929 ...
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Binlog end
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-11-11 09:05:14 6929 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151111 09:05:14 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Here's `syslog`:

```
Nov 11 08:48:21 localhost systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Nov 11 08:48:21 localhost mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 08:48:21 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
Nov 11 08:48:21 localhost mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 08:48:21 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
Nov 11 08:48:21 localhost mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 08:48:21 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Nov 11 08:48:21 localhost kernel: [ 4919.689076] audit: type=1400 audit(1447220901.895:21): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/usr/my.cnf" pid=6761 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=108 ouid=0
Nov 11 08:48:22 localhost systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Nov 11 08:55:33 localhost systemd[1]: session-16.scope: Cannot determine UID from slice user-0.slice
Nov 11 08:55:33 localhost systemd[1]: Started Session 16 of user root.
Nov 11 09:00:01 localhost CRON[6841]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && test -x /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail && test -x /usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Nov 11 09:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833511] php5-fpm invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833529] php5-fpm cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833582] CPU: 0 PID: 6914 Comm: php5-fpm Not tainted 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833589] Hardware name: Bochs Bochs, BIOS Bochs 01/01/2011
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833600]  0000000000000000 000000002c9946d9 ffff88000f5ff958 ffffffff817e8c09
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833609]  0000000000000000 ffff88001cf16e00 ffff88000f5ff9e8 ffffffff817e69ff
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833613]  ffffffff810c3d61 0000000000000000 0000000000000001 0000000000000000
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833616] Call Trace:
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833674]  [] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833682]  [] dump_header+0x8c/0x214
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833716]  [] ? __raw_callee_save___pv_queued_spin_unlock+0x11/0x20
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833739]  [] oom_kill_process+0x1e1/0x3b0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833744]  [] out_of_memory+0x556/0x5b0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833749]  [] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8c1/0xa10
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833771]  [] alloc_pages_current+0x91/0x100
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833776]  [] __page_cache_alloc+0xa0/0xc0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833780]  [] filemap_fault+0x14a/0x3f0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833790]  [] __do_fault+0x50/0xe0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833795]  [] handle_mm_fault+0xf5b/0x17e0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833804]  [] ? __wake_up+0x48/0x60
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833809]  [] ? __raw_callee_save___pv_queued_spin_unlock+0x11/0x20
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833826]  [] __do_page_fault+0x197/0x400
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833831]  [] trace_do_page_fault+0x37/0xa0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833840]  [] do_async_page_fault+0x19/0x70
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833848]  [] async_page_fault+0x28/0x30
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833855] Mem-Info:
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833865] active_anon:112864 inactive_anon:1012 isolated_anon:0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833865]  active_file:270 inactive_file:324 isolated_file:0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833865]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833865]  slab_reclaimable:2725 slab_unreclaimable:2449
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833865]  mapped:9930 shmem:16693 pagetables:1403 bounce:0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833865]  free:1156 free_pcp:30 free_cma:0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833873] Node 0 DMA free:1972kB min:88kB low:108kB high:132kB active_anon:12808kB inactive_anon:60kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:1260kB shmem:1660kB slab_reclaimable:252kB slab_unreclaimable:312kB kernel_stack:32kB pagetables:132kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833890] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 471 471 471
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833898] Node 0 DMA32 free:2652kB min:2732kB low:3412kB high:4096kB active_anon:438648kB inactive_anon:3988kB active_file:1080kB inactive_file:1296kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:507896kB managed:484772kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:38460kB shmem:65112kB slab_reclaimable:10648kB slab_unreclaimable:9484kB kernel_stack:1680kB pagetables:5480kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:120kB local_pcp:120kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:16600 all_unreclaimable? yes
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833906] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833910] Node 0 DMA: 17*4kB (UM) 6*8kB (UM) 4*16kB (U) 0*32kB 10*64kB (UM) 7*128kB (UEM) 1*256kB (M) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 1972kB
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833936] Node 0 DMA32: 205*4kB (UE) 161*8kB (E) 34*16kB (UE) 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2652kB
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833958] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833960] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833962] 17296 total pagecache pages
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833971] 0 pages in swap cache
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833974] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833976] Free swap  = 0kB
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833978] Total swap = 0kB
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833981] 130972 pages RAM
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833984] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833987] 5802 pages reserved
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833989] 0 pages cma reserved
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833991] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.833994] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834004] [  203]     0   203    31441      610      64       3        0             0 systemd-journal
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834019] [  210]     0   210    10965      164      21       3        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834030] [  498]   100   498    25075       65      20       3        0             0 systemd-timesyn
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834036] [  558]   104   558    64093      207      28       4        0             0 rsyslogd
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834042] [  565]     0   565     7135       76      18       3        0             0 systemd-logind
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834047] [  584]   105   584    10715      112      26       3        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834052] [  604]     0   604     7599       69      20       3        0             0 cron
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834058] [  607]     0   607    71148      215      39       3        0             0 accounts-daemon
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834062] [  651]     0   651     6015       95      15       3        0             0 vsftpd
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834068] [  736]     0   736    62752     2266      78       4        0             0 php5-fpm
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834073] [  857]     0   857    26139      485      49       3        0             0 sendmail-mta
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834079] [ 1143]     0  1143    17493      191      38       4        0         -1000 sshd
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834082] [ 1148]     0  1148     4330       41      13       3        0             0 agetty
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834085] [ 1161]     0  1161    58312      737      53       4        0             0 nginx
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834088] [ 1168]     0  1168     9184      202      22       3        0             0 systemd
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834091] [ 1169]     0  1169    14725      438      32       3        0             0 (sd-pam)
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834094] [ 1192]     0  1192    24962      257      52       3        0             0 sshd
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834097] [ 1210]     0  1210     5914      395      16       3        0             0 bash
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834099] [ 1382]  1001  1382    58355      884      51       4        0             0 nginx
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834103] [ 5879]  1001  5879    74907    22161     118       4        0             0 php5-fpm
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834106] [ 6339]  1001  6339    75760    22995     117       4        0             0 php5-fpm
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834109] [ 6341]  1001  6341    72891    20096     112       4        0             0 php5-fpm
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834112] [ 6403]   108  6403     1119       39       8       3        0             0 mysqld_safe
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834115] [ 6761]   108  6761   248107    29148     112       4        0             0 mysqld
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834118] [ 6820]     0  6820    24962      270      52       3        0             0 sshd
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834121] [ 6838]     0  6838     3216       61      12       3        0             0 sftp-server
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834124] [ 6912]  1001  6912    75446    14104      98       4        0             0 php5-fpm
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834126] [ 6914]  1001  6914    75006    13555      96       4        0             0 php5-fpm
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834129] Out of memory: Kill process 6761 (mysqld) score 233 or sacrifice child
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834552] Killed process 6761 (mysqld) total-vm:992428kB, anon-rss:116592kB, file-rss:0kB
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 09:05:14 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 09:05:14 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.983543] audit: type=1400 audit(1447221914.187:22): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/usr/my.cnf" pid=6929 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=108 ouid=0
Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost mysqld_safe[6403]: 151111 09:05:14 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I' running ubuntu 15.10, mysql 5.6.27, nginx 1.9.6, PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 (fpm-fcgi).

So, how to fix that?

And, being a newbie at mysql, I wonder why mysql is so fragile and can be so easily killed (and make the whole bunch of sites connected to it unavailable). How to make it more robust?

Comment: seems innodb_buffer_pool is set to a value more than the free one..reduce this in your my.cnf file and try starting the MySQL. hope it help

Answer (score 1):

"Nov 11 09:05:14 localhost kernel: [ 5931.834129] Out of memory: Kill process 6761 (mysqld) score 233 or sacrifice child"

You are crossing system memory and then kernel is killing highest user of memory - in your case that'd be mysqld.
Consider revising mysql global and per-thread variables in order to limit total usage under control.
You may use [this procedure to estimate MySQL memory usage](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/calculte-mysql-memory-usage-quick-stored-proc) or you might want to [fill in here](http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/) to check the usage details.

Also... Swapping is not good for MySQL, it's better to have swappiness set to 1-10 or 0 depending on your kernel version. Refer [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/04/28/oom-relation-vm-swappiness0-new-kernel/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding swap file to the system temporarily solved the problem: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

But swapping a database is, of course, far from perfect.

Comment: If MySQL has to swap, it will be slooooow.  Change the tunables.  How much RAM do you have _available_?  `SHOW VARIABLES;`